# Unable to send email from Laravel 5.2 using MailGun

Tags: mailgun, laravel-5

I am trying to use the built-in driver for Mailgun to send email. Here's what I have done so far.

Installed Guzzle driver.

Added the following to my config\services.php

```
'mailgun' => [
    'domain' => env('sandbox54d5c9ed96434d689f971fd3.mailgun.org'),
    'secret' => env('key-e800aa77cbda23ee8471dd5e'),
],
```

In my config\mail.php I have added 
    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'mailgun'),

However, now if I try to do forget password. It says we have sent an email but I don't get anything.

The domain is my sandbox domain name and secret is the API Key.

Am I missing something here or doing something wrong? How can I debug if there are some issues?

Comment: At the bottom of the `config\mail.php` there is a `pretend` option, make sure its set to false. `'pretend' => false,`

Comment: where did you find the sandbox.......mailgun.org?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for this late answer, just found your question while googling for something different and hope not too late. If you want to save the credentials in .env, do this in your config\services.php:

```
'mailgun' => [
    'domain' => env('MAILGUN_DOMAIN'),
    'secret' => env('MAILGUN_SECRET'),
],
```

Then in your .env file

```
MAILGUN_DOMAIN=sandbox54d5c9ed96434d689f971fd3.mailgun.org
MAILGUN_SECRET=key-e800aa77cbda23ee8471dd5e
```

In the config\services.php you just tell the key on .env file with:
`'setting' => env('KEY_IN_ENV')`
Laravel will then check if the key found and get the value from .env file:
`KEY_IN_ENV = setting_value`

Or simply like this in your config\services.php only:

```
'mailgun' => [
    'domain' => 'sandbox54d5c9ed96434d689f971fd3.mailgun.org',
    'secret' => 'key-e800aa77cbda23ee8471dd5e',
],
```

Good for you.